# How to add 1 month on 28 feb in android

Tags: java, android, date, calendar

I set Today is **Feb 28 2014** and i using the code :

```
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
```

The output is ***Mar 28 2014***

But i want to show ***Mar 31 2014***

what should i do ?

Comment: What is the logic behind output you want to show? Do you want always to move date to next month and set day to last one of that month? If original date would be `Feb 18 2014` should result also be `Mar 31 2014`?

Answer (score 2):

You can move date to next month, and then set its day to max value for current month

```
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);//move date to next month
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.getMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
  //set          day               to max value for current month
```

Comment: But only set to last day of month if, before adding a month to the date, this evaluates to true: `boolean isLastDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == cal.getMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);`